# Reading three files and writing shared items to a new file using Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have three text files. 
Two files (a.txt, b.txt) are formatted in the same way (> 100000000 rows, three columns of data) and 
one is union file from first column of both a.txt and b.txt. 

a.txt ('r')

```
MARCH2_MARCH2   2.3 0.1
MARCH2_MARC2    -0.22   0
MARCH2_MARCH5   -0.3    0.3
MARCH2_MARCH6   -1.4    0
MARCH2_MARCH7   0.1 0
MARCH2_SEPT2    -1.0    0
MARCH2_SEPT4    0.8 0
```

b.txt ('r')

```
MARCH2_MARCH2   2.2 0
MARCH2_MARCH2.1 0.2 0
MARCH2_MARCH3   -0.4    0.1111111
MARCH2_MARCH5   -0.3    0
MARCH2_MARCH6   -0.6    0
MARCH2_MARCH7   1.2 0
MARCH2_SEPT2    0.2 0
```

c.txt ('r')

```
MARCH2_MARCH2   
MARCH2_MARCH2.1
MARCH2_MARC2
MARCH2_MARCH5   
MARCH2_MARCH6   
MARCH2_MARCH7
MARCH2_SEPT2    
MARCH2_SEPT4
MARCH2_MARCH3
```

From these files I'd like to write new files as follows. 
 That is, insert two values within second and third column of each text file to the corresponded row which contains same value within first column (a[0] == c[0] or b[0] == c[0]). 
Thus, the total number of columns in new file might be five. If there is no matched value, I'd like to just insert "NA".

new.file ('w')

```
MARCH2_MARCH2   2.3 0.1 2.2 0
MARCH2_MARCH2.1 NA NA 0.2 0
MARCH2_MARC2    -0.2    0 NA NA
MARCH2_MARCH5   -0.3    0.3 -0.3 0
MARCH2_MARCH6   -1.4    0 -0.6  0
MARCH2_MARCH7   1.2 0 1.2   0
MARCH2_SEPT2    -1.0    0 0.2   0
MARCH2_SEPT4 0.8    0 NA NA
MARCH2_MARCH3 NA NA -0.4 0.1111111
```

I am looking for a solution and have tried something different including dictionary based parsing. Unfortunately, I am still new to python and all codes I made did not work properly. Please, give me your hand. 
 Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Please give at least an example of what you have tried, and how it was deficient.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your files are <kbd>TAB</kbd> delimeted, this should work:

```
values = collections.defaultdict(lambda : collections.defaultdict(lambda : "NA NA"))
inputfiles = ['a.txt', 'b.txt']
for fname in inputfiles:
  with open(fname) as infile:
    for line in infile:
      field, vals = line.strip().split('\t', 1)
      values[field][fname] = vals

with open('c.txt') as infile, open('d.txt', 'w') as outfile:
  for line in infile:
    field = line.strip()
    outfile.write("%s\t" %field)
    for fname in inputfiles:
      outfile.write("%s\t" %values[field][fname])
    outfile.write('\n')
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
MARCH2_MARCH2   -0.22   0       2.2 0   
MARCH2_MARCH2.1 NA NA   0.2 0   
MARCH2_MARC2    NA NA   NA NA   
MARCH2_MARCH5   -0.3    0.3     -0.3    0       
MARCH2_MARCH6   -1.4    0       -0.6    0       
MARCH2_MARCH7   0.1 0   1.2 0   
MARCH2_SEPT2    -1.0    0       0.2 0   
MARCH2_SEPT4    0.8 0   NA NA   
MARCH2_MARCH3   NA NA   -0.4    0.1111111
```

Comment: This will work for small data sets, but if the inputs files are very large this will use up a lot of memory.

Comment: @bj0: Absolutely right. However, very little else can be done (without a linear search of the file - so O(n^2)), unless the input files are sorted or something like that

Comment: Unfortunately, I've initially copied the codes you wrote but it doesn't work. Some errors were found including from first line. I modified some codes and there was still some errors found including from seventh line to call values.

Comment: On top of that, however I've tried to sort and size down both text files, they are actually super parsed and down-sized files compared with raw files. The size per one text file itself is about 5G.

Comment: @user2913161: Thanks for the bug report. I've fixed my code and added the output, given your examples in the files. As for your concerns about the file size, I'd recommend providing more information about how these files are sorted, etc (you should edit this info into your original post, so that everyone else can see it easily). With that information, I might be able to design a better algorithm for you